# How to test existing Angularjs overall performance (DOM rendering)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, optimization, performance-testing

I got an existing angularjs project for optimization. How can I find gaps like (memory leakage, performance on browser , Data rendering , screen got stuck kind of issues).
I tried Jmeter but its not showing javascript performance just shows page is navigated in few Milli seconds.
I tried to find with chrome profiling , I got some specific scenarios but not overall image.

How can I get overall performance results?

Comment: Hi https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Comment: You can try webpagetest.com  to check your application overall performance

Answer (score 2):

For testing solely client-side rendering performance you can use your favourite browser developer tools, i.e:

- [Firefox: Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/son/docs/Tools/Performance)
- [Chrome: Rendering Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/)
- [Microsoft Edge Dev Tools: Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/performance)

or go for a 3rd-party application/plugin like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)

If you want to combine page rendering performance test with the main load test you can still use JMeter for client-side performance testing, there is a [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) browser automation framework so you will be able to combine server-side performance test with client-side performance test. Additional information on page loading events can be obtained from the WebDriver Sampler via [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)

Comment: The answer was very helpful.